# Where can I find the source code for the translate/grab tool

Tags: python

You see I'm recreating the grab tool for a game engine based on LUA.

Problem is, I can't seem to figure out how exactly it works

Would be great if somebody could link me to the source code of the translate tool

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been decided that questions about Blender's source are (sadly), off-topic. Try asking on the #blendercoders IRC channel on Freenode.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Blender C/C++ source code.
These questions are considered outside the scope of this StackExchange as [defined in the help center](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Development questions should be asked of the developers directly instead, see the [contacting developers page of the blender wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Contact).